# Importing yahoo contacts using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo, yahoo-api

I have integrated importing contacts from gmail and outlook using javascript. They are providing javascript SDKs for the above. I did not find any SDK for yahoo.

The API docs provided by yahoo is no that much clear. Any help appreciated to implement this.

NB: I require a pure javascript level importig , not OAuth2 authentication process(i have done the gmail and outlook using SDKs[pure javascript, without Outh2], I want the same look and feel for this also)